# ReatctJS ComponentDidUpdate not firing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Simple example but not sure why I can't get it to work:

```
class Grid extends React.Component {    
    componentDidUpdate = () =>{
      alert('Should Fire')
    }
    render() {        
        return (<div>{this.props.name}</div>)
    }
}
class Application extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div><Grid name="test-grid" /></div>);
  }
}
```

The `componentDidUpdate` method does not fire in the Grid class.  Insight?

Comment: componentDidMount will do the trick. componentDidUpdate is for checking if there has been a state change or prop change . Without these changes it won't execute . But ComponentDidMount will run after the DOM has loaded and it will only run ONCE

Comment: I shall try it again on your advice.  Perhaps there is something I missed when accessing the DOM from this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you can use `componentDidMount()`. You are not updating the `props` which should trigger update event. See from the documentation of `componentDidUpdate()`:

> [`componentDidUpdate()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

As the following:

```
class Grid extends React.Component {    
    componentDidMount = () =>{
      alert('Should Fire')
    }
    render() {        
        return (<div>{this.props.name}</div>)
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't `componentDidUpdate` supposed to fire AFTER the component renders?  That's why I am using this method - I need access to wha's rendered in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate` function only fires when the parent component re-renders causing the child to re-render.

In your case the parent isn't re-rendering at all. Its just the initial render.

To detect an initial render, you would make use of `componentDidMount` function. You can see the componentDidUpdate function being fired if you have a state in parent that you update based on an interaction or any other way

```js
 class Grid extends React.Component {    
        componentDidMount(){
          alert('Should Fire')
        }
        componentDidUpdate() {
          alert('ComponentDidUpdate Should Fire');
        }
        render() {        
            return (<div>{this.props.name}</div>)
        }
    }
    class Application extends React.Component {
     state = {
        count: 0
     }
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
             <Grid name="test-grid" />
             <button onClick={()=>this.setState(prev => ({count: prev.count + 1}))}> increment</button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    
    ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: I need access to what is rendered in the DOM.  I cannot access that from `componentDidMount` because the component hasn't rendered yet.

Comment: componentDidMount is called only after the initial render and hence whatever you wish to access from DOM will be accessible in componentDidMount